# how I can add the last frame at the end of Video unit frame count of Video reach 29

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I want duplicate the last frame at each video until reach 29 frames

this is my code How i can doing with do not affect in resolution or fps

```
import cv2


vs = cv2.VideoCapture('Politics_news_3_p1_289.mp4')
last_frame_num = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)-1
height = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
width = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
fps = vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_co = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
duration = frame_co/fps
print('video resolution:', width, ' x ', height)
print('video framerate:', fps)
print('video duration:', duration)
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, last_frame_num)


while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imwrite('/Users/Downloads/ii.png',frame)
        cv2.imshow('last_frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
        break
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```